# why define operator<< and >> in a namespace break boost program_options?

Tags: c++, boost

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310053/using-boostprogram-options-with-enum-in-class-in-namespace), if I put the overloaded operator in the namespace it should just work. But I found it actually not working, compiler always complain that it cannot find the << or >>.

In following [example](https://godbolt.org/z/uGHLta), if I turn on the USE_NAMESPACE, compiling fails. But the >> and << actually work outside the program_options. If I turn off the ENABLE_PO it works fine.

What happens here? how could I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;
#define ENABLE_PO 1
#define USE_NAMESPACE 0
enum class test_enum_t {bar, foo};
#if USE_NAMESPACE
namespace test_enum
{
#endif

    template<typename istream_T>
    istream_T& operator>>(istream_T& in, test_enum_t& value)
    {
        std::string in_str;
        in >> in_str;
        if (in_str == "bar")
            value = test_enum_t::bar;
        else if(in_str == "foo")
            value = test_enum_t::foo;
        else
            in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return in;
    }

    template<typename ostream_T>
    ostream_T &operator<<(ostream_T &out, const test_enum_t& value) {
        if (value == test_enum_t::bar)
            out << "bar";
        else if (value == test_enum_t::foo)
            out << "foo";
        else
            out << "unknown-value";
        return out;
    }

#if USE_NAMESPACE
}
using namespace test_enum;
#endif

#if ENABLE_PO
int simple_options(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    test_enum_t test = test_enum_t::bar;
    po::options_description config("Configuration");
    config.add_options()
        ("help", "produce help message")
        ("in,i", po::value(&test)->default_value(test), "test enum class as input.")
        ;
    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, config),vm);
    po::notify(vm);
    if (vm.count("help")) {
        std::cout << config << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
#endif
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if ENABLE_PO
    simple_options(argc, argv);
#endif
    test_enum_t test;
    std::cout << "input bar or foo" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> test;
    if (std::cin.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "not a valid value";
        exit(1);
    }
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to put `test_enum_t` in the same namespace as the operators.  ADL requires the type and the function be in the same namespace.

Comment: this is difficult, in reality the operator template will be in a separated lib like magic_enum, which defines the operator templates in a namespace. So I cannot define all the enum_t in that namespace, which would be very messy. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: AFAIK for it to work the type and the operator need to be in the same namespace.

Comment: is there any way to do `using somenamespace::operator<<` for templates? or maybe specialization in another namesapce where the enum_t defined?

Comment: That should work.  Is it not?  You still need to put that in the namespace the enum is in.

Comment: Thanks it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you need ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup) to succeed.

If you can control POI (Point Of Instantiation) you can also actively `use` the names from the dedicated namespace instead. In this case, you need to `use` these names in the TU that defines `simple_options` before the point that instantiates the parsing code, e.g. where you define the [*Option Descriptions Component*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp523443552).

Here's a simplified version of the code that demonstrates it

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c07fc59677f1cbc)**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
enum class test_enum_t { bar, foo };

namespace test_enum {

    template <typename istream_T>
        istream_T& operator>>(istream_T& in, test_enum_t& value) {
            std::string in_str;
            in >> in_str;
            if (in_str == "bar")
                value = test_enum_t::bar;
            else if (in_str == "foo")
                value = test_enum_t::foo;
            else
                in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
            return in;
        }

    template <typename ostream_T>
        ostream_T& operator<<(ostream_T& out, const test_enum_t& value) {
            if (value == test_enum_t::bar)
                out << "bar";
            else if (value == test_enum_t::foo)
                out << "foo";
            else
                out << "unknown-value";
            return out;
        }

}

using test_enum::operator<<;
using test_enum::operator>>;

test_enum_t simple_options(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    namespace po = boost::program_options;

    test_enum_t test = test_enum_t::bar;
    po::options_description config("Configuration");

    config.add_options()("help", "produce help message")(
            "in,i", po::value(&test)->default_value(test),
            "test enum class as input.");

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, config), vm);
    po::notify(vm);
    if (vm.count("help")) {
        std::cout << config << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    return test;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Command line input: " << simple_options(argc, argv) << "\n";

    std::cout << "input bar or foo" << std::endl;
    if (test_enum_t test; std::cin >> test) {
        std::cout << test << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "not a valid value";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_program_options
./a.out -i bar <<<foo
Command line input: bar
input bar or foo
foo
```