# boost::lexical_cast not recognizing overloaded istream operator

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading, istream, lexical-cast

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost\lexical_cast.hpp>

struct vec2_t
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& istream, vec2_t& v)
{
    istream >> v.x >> v.y;

    return istream;
}

int main()
{
    auto v = boost::lexical_cast<vec2_t>("1231.2 152.9");

    std::cout << v.x << " " << v.y;

    return 0;
}
```

I am receiving the following compile error from Boost:

> Error 1   error C2338: Target type is neither std::istream`able nor std::wistream`able

This seems straightforward enough, and I have been hitting my head against the desk for the last hour. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Wasted my day dealing with this ;(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's 2-phase lookup at play.

You need to enable the overload using ADL, so `lexical_cast` will find it in the second phase.

So, you should move the overload into namespace `mandala`

Here's a completely fixed example (you should also use `std::skipws`):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f1184af25ff7526)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

namespace mandala
{
    struct vec2_t {
        float x,y;
    };    
}

namespace mandala
{
    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& istream, vec2_t& v) {
        return istream >> std::skipws >> v.x >> v.y;
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto v = boost::lexical_cast<mandala::vec2_t>("123.1 15.2");
    std::cout << "Parsed: " << v.x << ", " << v.y << "\n";
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tend to say **["it's a hyperlink"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup/8111750#8111750)**

Comment: Edited my post eliminating the `mandala` namespace I had previously. Same error occurs.

Comment: @cmbasnett **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01278169168ab3f3)** I'm pretty sure there is an observation error involved (or terribly broken compilers)

Comment: Directly copy-pasting that code on Coliru into Visual Studio 2013 and compiling it yields the same error. :S

Comment: im running VS 2013 too, and it compiles for me. Do you have update 4?

Comment: @cmbasnett I have figured out the other error in your implementation, see updated answer. I've tested this on VS2013 too (see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f1184af25ff7526)** though)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/5KgTGxO.png (It is pathethic how MSVC takes well over a minute to compile that on my box though o.O)

Comment: @sp2danny Installing Update 4 now.

Comment: @cmbasnett That's not required. I run v120 (RTM). You have likely just not spotted that you got a different error.