# How to pass a string to "validation_error" method from Boost 1.46?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to compile a program released by [Dalal and Triggs](http://pascal.inrialpes.fr/soft/olt/) which uses the Boost libraries. I got an error in the Boost method `validation_error` due to the differences between version which the authors used (`1.35`) and the one that I'm using (`1.46`).

In the [old version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/validation_error.html), the `validation_error` method used by the authors had the following structure:

```
validation_error(const std::string & what);
```

And the [version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/program_options/validation_error.html) of Boost I'm running has the following:

```
validation_error(kind_t kind, const std::string & option_value = "", 
                 const std::string & option_name = "");
```

In the code, the authors are passing a `string` to the old `validation_error` method (example below).

```
std::ostringstream ost;
ost << "value " << *value
      << " greater than max value " << max;
throw po::validation_error(ost.str());
```

How can I pass this `string` to the new version of `validation_error`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
throw boost::program_options::validation_error(
    boost::program_options::validation_error::invalid_option_value,
    "option name",
    *value
);
```

or

```
throw boost::program_options::invalid_option_value(ost.str());
```

Comment: What does `invalid_option_value` do? And `"option name"`?

Comment: You are describing validation error, in 1.35 the only option was to give string with description, what is wrong. In 1.46, you have to describe problem in a more systematic way: you tell what was wrong from kind_t enum (please check http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/validation_error.html), also you pass wrong value and option name which was not validated.

Comment: How do I also pass the value of `max`?

Comment: Do you have to pass max value in exception? Isn't it known anyway? There is also boost::program_options::invalid_option_value which takes only string as a constructor argument. invalid_option_value is subclass of validation_error, so it could be used as drop-in replacement.