# How can the boost program options library be used to parse a config file with repeated sections?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

How can a file like this be parsed, especially in the Devices section?
Also, does boost handle the input stream, or does that have be handled by additional code?

```
[Configuration]
IPAddress=192.168.1.1
Device Port=12345
Management Port = 54321

[Devices]
main server DEADBEEF 0
sales FEEDBEEF 1
marketing DEADDEED  2
```

I need all three columns under Devices, which are a description, MAC address and a register number.

This article seems close but, I want to do this with a file:
[Handle complex options with Boost's program_options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935587/handle-complex-options-with-boosts-program-options)

I suppose I can structure the devices like this:

```
[Device]
description='main server'
mac_address=DEADBEEF
register=0

[Device]
description-...
mac_address=...
register=...
```

Comment: I see two sections: Configuration and Devices. Where is the repeated section?

Comment: I.e. How to repeat items are devices?

Comment: Within a section, you are hoping to parse a duplicate key=value pair?