# How does the parse_config_file of boost program options parse multitoken

Tags: c++, parsing, syntax, boost-program-options, configuration-files

i like to read a vector using boost program options with multitoken and from a config file file.
using:

```
std::vector<int> numbers
po::options_description desc ( "Allowed Arguments" );
desc.add_options()
( "numbers,n", po::value< std::vector< int > > ( &numbers)->multitoken(), "my numbers" );

std::ifstream ifs ( "config.ini" , std::ifstream::in );
po::store ( po::parse_config_file ( ifs , desc ), vm );
po::notify ( vm );
```

but my now I have to define every value in my config.ini in separate row. like

```
numbers = 0
numbers = 1
numbers = 3
numbers = 5
```

is there a way/syntax to define all number in one line such as:
    numbers = [0 1 3 5] # this does not work

Thanks
Markus

Comment: Does the solution offered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2939249/820657) not help?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp163379208), one line configures one value.

However, you could read the value for numbers as a string, then parse with a regex or similar to get the individual values.

Comment: Thanks Phil,
Thats how I implemented it but I was hoping to find a better solution :-)